# iOS Application Rejected iTunes TestFlight: Touch ID Implemented

Tags: ios, testflight, touch-id

I had uploaded binary to TestFlight, but my application has gotten rejected by apple.

See below the reason mentioned:

*"Design Preamble We found that your app or app extension requires users to unlock app content using Touch ID, which is not a permitted use"*

I have integrated TouchID feature to log in to my application. But the rejection says that it isn't a permitted use.
Let me know if anyone knows anything about it.

Comment: Can user login into the app without using touchid, i mean by entering their credentials etc?

Comment: not all iOS devices have touch ID. Is there a way for such devices to use your app?

Comment: @Madhu Thanks for the question, which actually worked as solution for me. In order to incorporate TouchID in app, one must implement an alternate to get logged into your application. The problem with my application was, I had integrated only TouchID to unlock the content of the application.